# _Typeerror ( type 'String' is not a subtype of 'int' of 'index' ) Error

Tags: flutter, dart, typeerror

When I pass this code, this throws an `_Typeerror`.

```
DocumentSnapshot userDoc =
        await firestore.collection('users').doc(_uid.value).get();
    final userData = userDoc.data()! as dynamic;
    String name = userData['name'];
    String profilePhoto = userData['profilePhoto'];
    int likes = 0;
    int followers = 0;
    int following = 0;
    bool isFollowing = false;
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: What language are you programming in? A type-error doesn't have any meaning without knowledge of the environment and especially the language. Please [edit] your question to tell us (with a tag for the language). And [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), not even errors. Copy-paste *all* text as text into your questions.

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I use dart language

Answer (score 0):

You try it:

```
DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await firestore.collection('users').doc(_uid.value).get();
    final userData = JsonDecoder(userDoc.data()!); // ==> replace this 
    String name = userData['name'];
    String profilePhoto = userData['profilePhoto'];
    int likes = 0;
    int followers = 0;
    int following = 0;
    bool isFollowing = false;
```

Comment: I try this code but show error

Comment: Please read [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers without any kind of explanation of what you changed, what the problem was, or how your change will fix that problem, are discouraged. Such answers like this also tend to promote [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which really isn't a good thing.